# Convert an entire range to uppercase without looping through all the cells

Tags: excel, vba, range, uppercase

right now I'm using the following code to convert a list of ticker symbols from lowercase to upper case letters:

```
Dim Tickers As String
Dim n As Integer
For n = 2 To Last
    Tickers = UCase(W.Cells(n, 1).Value)
    W.Cells(n, 1).Value = Tickers
Next n
```

Is there a method I can use to convert the whole range in one line?  something like:

```
Range("A1:A20").convertouppercasesomehow
```

Comment: Why don't you want to loop over each cell?

Comment: @Jack I know this is ancient, but the answer to your question is: it's a very very bad idea. Super slow.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Is there a method I can use to convert the whole range in one line?

Yes you can convert without looping. Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    [A1:A20] = [INDEX(UPPER(A1:A20),)]
End Sub
```

Alternatively, using a variable range, try this:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A20")
    rng = Evaluate("index(upper(" & rng.Address & "),)")
End Sub
```

As per your example

```
W.Range("A1:A20") = [index(upper(A1:A20),)]
```

**Explanation**

There are two parts to `[A1:A20] = [INDEX(UPPER(A1:A20),)]`

***PART 1***

As shown above, `[A1:A20]` is nothing but just a short way of writing `Range("A1:A20")`

**PART 2**

`[INDEX(UPPER(A1:A20),)]`

`Index` and `Upper` are worksheet functions. So you can use `Application.Worksheetfunction.Index()` but since we don't have an equivalent of `UPPER` like `Application.Worksheetfunction.UPPER()`, we can only write it as `[cell] = [UPPER(cell)]`

Now with that line we are instructing `VBA` to return an array and this is where `INDEX` comes into play. (*As we are aware, there are two forms of the `INDEX` function: the array form and the reference form.*) By not specifying a row or a column of the array, we are simply letting Excel know that we want the whole array. (*Mentioned in VBA help as well*) So basically what we are doing is converting each cell in `[A1:A20]` into uppercase

Comment: +1, Nice one. I bet you can't explain how it works in one line :).

Comment: @DougGlancy: What's the wager? :P

Comment: @DougGlancy: Ha ha ha. I am already beyond the daily cap of upvotes so anymore upvotes won't make a difference. But if I am ever in your town then the beer is on you! :) Gimme sometime, and I will update the post.

Comment: That would be my very great pleasure.

Comment: @DougGlancy: `I bet you can't explain how it works in one line` BTW I lost the bet if I look at it in another way ;) I took approx 14 lines to explain it :P

Comment: Wow! Don't know we can use `Worksheetfunction`'s in that way!:)

Comment: Is there any chance this could be adapted to be applied to the currently selected range? (Or as a `Function ToUpper( ByRef iRange As Range ) As Range`?)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Hi, I tried to use your solution, but I didn't want the range to be hard coded, so I did this- `Range(Cells(r1,c1), Cells(r2,c2))=[INDEX(UPPER(Range(Cells(r1,c1),Cells(r2,c2))),)]` where r1,r2,c1,c2 are variables, but the whole range was filled with "#NAME?" any idea? thx!

Comment: is it possible to use a range object instead of a range address?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thumbs up for this great solution. Can you tell WHY we need the INDEX part ? I tried without it (`[A1:A20] = [UPPER(A1:A20)]`) which indeed does not work, but I have trouble figuring out the role of that `INDEX` here

Comment: @PatrickHonorez: I have explained the role of Index at the end of the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

<s>You can't do it in one line like that, but</s> you can do it for a given range like:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A20")
    For Each c In Rng
        c.Value = UCase(c.Value)
    Next c
End Sub
```

Which is rather simple and intuitive.

Comment: Isn't this still a loop?

Comment: Yes it is. This solution is simple to understand but not nearly as impressive as @SiddharthRout's solution.

Answer (score 2):

from what i gathered from various sources:

```
Function UcaseRangeAsArray(TargetRng As Range) As Variant()
Dim Arr()    
Arr = Evaluate("INDEX(UPPER(" & TargetRng.Address(External:=True) & "),)")    
UcaseRangeAsArray = Arr
Erase Arr
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another "one liner hack":

```
Sub UCaseRange(rng As Range)
    rng = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(UCase(Join( _
        WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng), vbBack)), vbBack))
End Sub
```

This assumes, that none of your cells contain the vbBack character (ASCII code 8).

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the elegant answer put forth by [Peter Albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1867581/peter-albert), the [WorksheetFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx)'s [Transpose](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) function has some old fashioned limits; specifically there is a ceiling of 65,535 (max unsigned integer -1) elements that can be flipped. Bulk loading a variant array, processing 'in-memory' and subsequently returning the modified values to the worksheet can overcome that limit.

```
Sub test()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        makeUpper .Range("A2:A1000000")
    End With
End Sub

Sub makeUpper(rng As Range)
    Dim v As Long, vUPRs As Variant
    With rng
        vUPRs = .Value2
        For v = LBound(vUPRs, 1) To UBound(vUPRs, 1)
            vUPRs(v, 1) = UCase(vUPRs(v, 1))
        Next v
        .Cells = vUPRs
    End With
End Sub
```

This processes very quickly. 100K cells of data typically takes less than half a second and 1M cells can be converted in 4-6 seconds.

---

<sub>This is the type of sub procedure that can benefit from working on cells in the [Application.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/28700020#28700020) for boilerplate framwework to process cells within the Selection.</sub>

Comment: Does not work f going thru Row aka range("A1:AZ1").  Using simple   

     For Each Cell In rng
          Cell.Value = UCase(Cell)
     Next Cell