# Excel to Uppercase VBA without Looping

Tags: excel, uppercase

```
Sub Sample()

    [A1:A20] = [INDEX(UPPER(A1:A20),)]

End Sub
```

Hi,  For the above code that was provided by [Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells),  is it possible  to  change the 20 to a variable such as last row in a worksheet?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Not with this very technique, i don't think.

Comment: I second @pnuts suggestion as well. But if you are targeting a specific range, try my answer. It's the same as what Sid did, he just went via the `[]` shortcut for `Evaluate`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub UpperCase()

    Dim TargetRng As Range, LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set TargetRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

    TargetRng = Evaluate("INDEX(UPPER(" & TargetRng.Address & "),)")

End Sub
```

`[]` is just shorthand for `Evaluate`. Using the whole word has no penalties and can be used with VBA as well. Just tried it and it works.

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to put the largest amount of rows possible. For Excel 2007 would be 1048576