# excel macro column auto-fill

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet which I am cleaning and using macros to help. My column 'C' has temperature data. Like with all data, there is some missing. How would I write a macro that would auto-fill the missing spot with previous data?

For example:

```
  C                                       C

1  37                                   1  37
2  35                                   2  35
3                   -------->           3  35  
4  37                                   4  37
5  36                                   5  36
```

The spot C3 has been filled with C2's data.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: is it possible to have two empty cells in contiguous rows (say, `35,<blank>,<blank>,36`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub FixC()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        If Cells(i, "C") = "" Then
            Cells(i, "C") = Cells(i - 1, "C")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 For a vba solution.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need VBA for this?

Do this

1. Select Col C
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>
3. Click on `Special`
4. Next Click on `Blanks`
5. Click Ok
6. All Empty cells are now selected. Press the <kbd>=</kbd> key and then the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow key
7. Lastly press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and you are done.

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: +1! I thought about using in VBA formula from your another answer `[C2:C10] = [INDEX(IF(C2:C10="",C1:C9,C2:C10),)]`, but it works only in case when there is no two empty cells in contiguous rows and my conscience would be guilty:)

Comment: @simoco: `my conscience would be guilty:) – simoco 49 secs ago` Not about just my post but if you use any other post as a reference, you should always give that person a credit in your post. Then you will notice that you will never feel guilty again ;) For [EXAMPLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769948/excel-vba-capitalizing-all-selected-cells-in-column-on-double-click/21773083#21773083)

Answer (score 0):

How would I write that macro:
This contains only snippets.

loop over all cells in the column:
`for each cell in ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Cells`

if the cell value is not empty -> save the value to a variable
`If cell.value <> Empty then lastCellValue = cell.value`

if the cell value is empty -> write the saved cell value into the cell
`Else cell.value = lastCellValue`

also:
if more than x (e.g. 20) cells in a row were empty, break from loop