# Easy VBA formula excel

Tags: excel, vba

I got a long list (1 million rows) with negative values. I need a formula (VBA) that automatically divides all the values lower then -40000 by 1000. (ex: -120000 is 120) (ex 2: -10000 is -10000)

The column is D.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this one (using [**SiddharthRout's approach from this A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells/19986324#19986324)):

```
Sub test()
    [A1:A100000] = [INDEX(IF(A1:A100000<-40000,A1:A100000/1000,A1:A100000),)]
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In E1 enter:

**=IF(D1<-40000,D1/1000,D1)**  and copy down