# Capitalizing all characters Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, capitalization

This should capitalize every character but I get `type mismatch` error.
It works fine for other worksheets that have similar data but for no reason it gives me mismatch error. Please help

```
Private Sub allUpper(ByRef sh As Worksheet)
        Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, j As Long

        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.UsedRange) > 0 Then
            arr = sh.UsedRange  'one interaction with the sheet
            For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)         'each "row"
                For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)     'each "col"
                    arr(i, j) = UCase(RTrim(Replace(arr(i, j), Chr(10), vbNullString)))
                Next
            Next
            sh.UsedRange = arr  'second interaction with the sheet
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why Loop? See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error (`#N/A`, etc.) somewhere in your data.

You can add a check for that to prevent the run time error:

```
If Not IsError(arr(i, j)) Then
    arr(i, j) = UCase(RTrim(Replace(arr(i, j), Chr(10), vbNullString)))
End If
```