# Text Function for multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to know if there is an alternative method (than loops) for using a text function on multiple cells.

For example, the below code work correctly for lookups

```
Range("c2:c6").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("a2:a6"), Range("a2:b6"), 2, 0)
```

However I get an error with the below for text functions

```
Range("c2:c6").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Range("A2:A6"), "000000")
```

Comment: Could you share what error you get. Since an error could be so many of things.

Comment: What error do you get? Do you want to insert array formula? Because Excel function TEXT doesn't accept range as a first parameter (unless it is array formula).

Comment: Run-time error '13' Type Mismatch

Comment: You can read more about.worksheetfunction.text here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841121.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surly all you want to do is format the cells and copy the values?

Like below?

```
    With Range("C2:C6")
        .Value = Range("A2:A6").Value
        .NumberFormat = "000000"
    End With
```

The macro recorder gave me similar to above with some optimisations

Using formula

```
Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-2],""000000"")"
Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-2],""000000"")"
Range("C4").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-2],""000000"")"
Range("C5").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-2],""000000"")"
Range("C6").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-2],""000000"")"
```

Or something a little bit more dynamic

```
For Each cell In Range("C2:C6")
    cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-2],""000000"")"
Next
```

Comment: Hi, I currently use formula's however my preference is to use the text function if possible

Comment: I have amended above code. The last one of the three is probably the best one to use, as you can change the range easily. If you wanted to go further with this you could work out the last row in A and then use that for the last range row number in the loop

Answer (score 3):

One line code

```
Sub Sample()
    [C2:C6] = [INDEX("'" & TEXT(A2:A6,"000000"),)]
End Sub
```

If you want explanation on this then see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. In noticed that in both your answer and in Rory's answer you guys put an apostrophe (although in slightly different places). The code seems to yield the same results if the apostrophe isn't there. Is there a reason it was added?

Comment: If the cells are not formatted as text and you have long numbers then you will have to add `'` else you will see the numbers in scientific notation. :) For example in any new excel worksheet type `100000000000` in Cell A1. What do you see? `1E+11` now try `'100000000000`

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to avoid loops you can use `Evaluate`:

```
Range("c2:c6").Value = Range("c2:c6").Worksheet.Evaluate("INDEX(TEXT(A2:A6,""'000000""),)")
```

Comment: ++AH! Beat you after a long time :P

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
Sub dural()
    Range("C1:C6").Formula = "=Text(A1,""000000"")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I currently use formulas however my preference is to use the text function if possible