# Insert Formula with variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to insert Formula in Column "G" =Text(A3, 'mmmm") so that it updates each cell with Month based on date/time in column A.

xcWks.Range("G" & rCount).Formula = "=TEXT("A"& rCount, mmmm)"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652854/text-function-for-multiple-cells

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

```
xcWks.Range("G" & rCount).Formula = "=TEXT(A" & rCount & ",""mmmm"")"
```

which will generate the following formula if `rCount` was, for instance, `3`:

```
=TEXT(A3,"mmmm")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but its not working. I have a running code which extracts outlook data to excel sheet. i wanted to insert this formula. Column "A" has Date/Time, i want to fill column "G" (to the last row) with month name based on column "A" date.

Comment: @PuneetSoni Code works for me - what error are you getting?

Comment: no error but it does not fill anything. Cells are blank

Comment: is it because my rCount is assigned earlier in the code as "rCount=rCount+1"

Comment: @PuneetSoni Without seeing the rest of your code, it is very hard to tell.  P.S.  Did you follow the link in the comment from Slai.  There is a good chance that you don't need a loop for this.  But, then again, the other stuff you are doing in your existing code may mean that a loop is better.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in question

> I am looking to insert Formula in Column "G"

I am assuming you want to enter formula in `Column G`, thus try

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = xcWks.Range("A" & xcWks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row with data using Colunm A
xcWks.Range("G2:G" & lastRow).Formula = "=TEXT(A2,""mmmm"")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much guys. I had an counter "intRow" defined earlier in my code which i used along with rCount and it worked like a charm.

excWks.Cells(intRow, 7).Formula = "=TEXT(A" & rCount & ",""mmmm"")"