# Convert entire range to lowercase without looping through cells Indirect

Tags: vba, excel, range, lowercase

I'm looking at VBA code that takes an entire range of cells and converts them into lowercase. I found the following:

```
[A1:A20] = [index(lower(A1:A20),)]
```

This works fine for a fixed range (don't entirely understand syntax, but found the following post:)

[Post detailing code above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells)

My problem is this:

I would like to be able to set the range dynamically as I'm dealing with changing range sizes. However, the following doesn't work, and I can't seem to be able to use INDIRECT() either in VBA.

```
Range("A1:A" & n) = [index(lower(Range("A1:A" & n)),)]
```

Is there a way to make this work? 
I would really like to avoid using a for loop as I suspect this should be a lot faster..

Comment: Leave a space between `&` and `n` like so: `Range("A1:A" & n)`

Comment: VBA automatically formats it the right way - I've tried again with spaces just in case but same problem. I get #VALUE errors in my sheet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
Range("A1:A" & n) = Application.Evaluate("index(lower(A1:A" & n & "),)")
```

Comment: This is the correct answer based on the question - square brackets are shorthand notation for `Evaluate` in VBA but only take a string literal, whereas `Evaluate` will accept a concatenated string.

Comment: There has been a lot of bantering about the [LOWER](https://goo.gl/GMzwTs) and [UPPER](https://goo.gl/WXHHZ4) functions which are actually paralelled with VBA's [LCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264497.aspx) and [UCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264252.aspx) functions. What hasn't been mentioned is that VBA has no equivalent to the worksheet's native [PROPER](https://goo.gl/9F1oDG) functions and this is an excellent candidate to put that to use.

Answer (score 6):

Looping through the worksheet's cell will slow this down. Grab all of the cell data, process it in memory and then dump the result back to the worksheet.

```
Sub makeLower()
    Dim v As Long, vLWRs As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            vLWRs = .Value2
            For v = LBound(vLWRs, 1) To UBound(vLWRs, 1)
                vLWRs(v, 1) = LCase(vLWRs(v, 1))
            Next v
            .Cells = vLWRs
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Tested on 50K cell in 0.3 seconds, 1M cells in 6.78 seconds.