# Date information in a format Excel doesn't recognize as a Date

Tags: vba, excel, datetime, date-format

I have a generated file coming from a system the date format of this file is like this `Mar 28 2016  4:55:54:380PM` my script in VBA doesn't recognize this as date or rather Excel doesn't recognize this as a date format but only a string. Is there other way around?

Comment: do you need the date and time or just date?

Comment: i just need the date..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that you need just the date:

```
Sub dateTest()
    Dim d As Date
    s = "Mar 28 2016 4:55:54:380PM"
    s = Left(s, 11)
    d = DateSerial(Year(s), Month(s), Day(s))
    Debug.Print d
End Sub
```

> 28.03.2016

To iterate over some dataset:

```
Sub dateIteration()
    Dim d As Date, v As Variant
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

    For Each r In rng
        v = Left(r.Value, 11)
        d = DateSerial(Year(v), Month(v), Day(v))

        ' Do something with d
        ' Print it to worksheet, maybe?
        r.Value = d
    Next r
End Sub
```

To iterate over non-contiguous ranges with minimal code clutter:

```
Sub helperSub()
    Call dateIteration(Range("A1:A10"))
    Call dateIteration(Range("Z1:Z10"))
    Call dateIteration(Range("H1:M89"))
End Sub

Sub dateIteration(rng As Range)
    Dim d As Date, v As Variant

    For Each r In rng
        v = Left(r.Value, 11)
        d = DateSerial(Year(v), Month(v), Day(v))

        ' Do something with d
        ' Print it to worksheet, maybe?
        r.Value = d
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: If the syntax is the same, you can iterate over the data and apply the same algorithm.

Comment: what if im going to use this method to remove 2 or 3 more columns? how can i do it?

Comment: To iterate over several columns? Just define those columns as part of the range. `Set rng = Range("A1:C10")` and it will run the macro on all cells within that range.

Comment: Alteratively, you can define the macro to take a `Range` as argument and use a helper sub to run the macro several times on each individual range. This will be more useful if you aren't working with a contiguous range.

Comment: what i did is use another foor loop for the other column though it's feels like repetitive, column from H, K L, Z random columns...

Comment: See updated answer for an example on how to do this. But we're venturing off-topic for this question. If you need help with iteration, you should post a new question.

Comment: Preface it with `If r.Value <> ""`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a 2 line code ;)

I am assuming that the range is from `A1:A20`. Please amend as applicable

```
Sub Sample()
    [A1:A20].NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
    [A1:A20] = [index(DATE(MID(A1:A20,8,4),MONTH(1&LEFT(A1:A20,3)),MID(A1:A20,5,2)),)]
End Sub
```

[image]

If you want to understand what this code does then see the explanation that I have given [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Public Function stringtodate(mytext) As Date
    str1 = Split(mytext, " ")
    str2 = UBound(str1)
    If str2 > 2 Then
        If LCase(Left(str1(0), 3)) = "mar" Then
            mon = "03"
        End If
        stringtodate = str1(1) & "-" & mon & "-" & str1(2)
    Else
        'not a valid date
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the Date format within VBA #MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss.sss PM#?