# VBA Excel - changing case to Proper Case

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to Stackoverflow so hopefully I have posted this question in the right place.

I'm having trouble getting my code to work in VBA. I want it to select columns D:F until the last cell value. With this selection, I would like to change the case of the cells (they are currently uppercase) to Proper case.

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim range As Variant

With Worksheets("Overdue PO")
    Lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    .range("D2:F" & Lastrow).Select
    range = Selection.Value
End With

Application.Proper (range)
```

It currently selects the range until the bottom row, but it doesn't change the case of text. No error appears when running the code.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells Similarly you can use `[A1:A20] = [INDEX(PROPER(A1:A20),)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub test()

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim range As range
Dim c As range


With Worksheets("Overdue PO")
Lastrow = Columns("D:F").Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues,   SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    .range("D2:F" & Lastrow).Select
    Set range = Selection
End With

For Each c In range
    c.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(c.Value)
Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: This works well too :) thanks for your help! @jcarroll

Comment: I would probably recommend combing the LastRow = ... line from my code with Scott's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer

With Worksheets("Overdue PO")
    Lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("D2:F" & Lastrow).Value = .Evaluate("INDEX(PROPER(D2:F" & Lastrow & "),)")
End With
```

It will be near instant, without the need for loops.

Also using `.Select` or `.Activate` also slow down the code, aoid them if possible by referring to the cells directly.

Comment: @Amy in about 7-8 minutes you will be able to choose one to mark as correct.  You do this by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer.  Please come back and mark one as correct, it is something only you can do and it will close out the question as being answered.

Comment: @Amy yes you have.

Comment: @SiddharthRout just standing on the shoulders of giants like yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(range)` should do it. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx for documentation on `WorksheetFunction`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use this with a named range, and was kindly provided the following code. Perhaps it will assist someone else:

```
Sub m_MakeProper()
'2/8/2018
'
Application.Volatile True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
'
Worksheets("test").Activate
'
Dim LastRow                       As Long
Dim LastCol                       As Integer
Dim cell                          As Variant
Dim thiswksht                     As Worksheet
Dim thiswb                        As Workbook
'
'
Set thiswksht = ActiveSheet
If thiswksht.AutoFilterMode Then
    AutoFilterMode = False
End If
'
With thiswksht
    LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
'
Cells(1, 1).Activate
Rows(1).find("Status").Select
Range(ActiveCell.Address, Cells(LastRow, ActiveCell.Column)).Select
Selection.Name = "c_P_Status"
With Range("c_P_Status")
    .Value = Application.Evaluate("INDEX(PROPER(" & .Address & "),0)")
End With
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Ops, obviously missed getting it all in the correct place. Thanks