# Capitalize Dynamic Range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range, uppercase

*(Coding rookie posting first ever question so please pardon my mistakes)*

I'm trying to learn simple methods of data validation. I read another post similar to what I'm doing: [convert-entire-range-to-uppercase,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells) but it doesn't work when I change the range to fit my needs. Couldn't find anything else that addressed this.

I have an Excel column named "Block" that appears in different locations in different workbooks, and I need to capitalize any letters that occur in that column. I think the code works as intended until the final line, which results in "#NAME?" filling the whole range.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim BlockColumn As Long
Dim BlockRange As Range

    'defines LastColumn, LastRow & BlockColumn
    LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("a1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("a1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
    BlockColumn = Cells.Find(What:="Block", After:=Range("a1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

    'capitalizes any text in BlockColumn
    Set BlockRange = Range(Cells(2, BlockColumn), Cells(LastRow, BlockColumn))
    BlockRange = [UPPER(BlockRange)]
```

Aside from wondering where I made a mistake, I'm sure I've over-complicated this. Could someone show me a way to rethink or simplify it? I was also wondering the general pros and cons to accomplishing a task like this via looping (as opposed to this method), but not sure if this is the place to ask that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` is shorthand for Evaluate and does not accept variables.

You will need to actually use Evaluate.

You also need INDEX to not overwrite the entire range with the first value.

```
blockRange.value = blockRange.Parent.Evaluate("INDEX(UPPER(" & blockRange.Address & "),)")
```

Comment: `[]` *used like this* is shorthand for `Evaluate`. Square brackets can also be used to declare hidden enum members with otherwise illegal names, e.g. `[_Default]`. Crazy huh! Feels good to upvote one of your *answers* (and not a *comment*) at last! =)