# Replace "." with "/" macro in vba change order of numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change "." with "/" with a macro in Excel vba, it works, but when I activate the macro it changes the value of the cell from 10.11.2016 to 11/10/2016. 
Why does it change the order? The cell doesn't have any format.

```
Range("D1").Select
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell doesn't have the format but it is mirroring the format from the regional settings. Check **Control Panel** | **Clock and Region** | **Region**. The moment you replace the text, it becomes a date and then it simply picks up the format from regional settings.

Try this

```
With Range("D1")
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = Replace(.Value, ".", "/")
End With
```

What I am doing here is converting the format of the cell to text and then replacing the characters.

> > Great, it works! But can I also replace "." with "/" in the entire column D with this method without using a loop? If yes how? Thank you – Masca2056 7 mins ago

Try this. I am assuming 10 is the last row.

```
Sub Sample()
    Columns(4).NumberFormat = "@"
    [D1:D10] = [INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(D1:D10,".","/"),)]
End Sub
```

See this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells/19986324#19986324) for an explanation of using the above method.

Comment: Great, it works! 
But can I also replace "." with "/" in the entire column D with this method without using a loop? If yes how?
Thank you

Comment: You could replace `Range("D1")` with `Columns(4)` and `.Value = Replace(.Value, ".", "/")` with `.Replace ".", "/"` to do the whole column. **Edit**... but saying that, it brings back your original problem.

Comment: @Masca2056 : I have edited the post. You may have to refresh the page to see it