# How to sum first digit of series of numbers

Tags: excel, vba

the following numbers begin in cell B5: 23  34  45  56  45  54
I want to sum the first digit of each, and display the result in cell C9

I tried different adjustments to the code below.

```
Sub sum_first_digit()

    Dim colnum As Integer
    Dim sumfirst As Integer

    sumfirst = 0

    For colnum = 2 To 7 Step 1
        cellref = Cells(5, colnum)
        sumfirst = sumfirst + (Left(celref, 1))
    Next colnum

    Range("C9").Value = sumfirst


End Sub
```

Expected cell C9 to have the number 23.

Actual is

> Runtime Error 13: Type Mismatch

Comment: No, the values are in B5, C5, D5, etc.  Thanks.

Comment: You have hit the jack pot in solutions. You should kindly accept one (please see the check mark box next to the solution that happens to tickle your fancy)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why a formula couldn't work. In C9 use,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(B5:G5&0))
'an array formula that will skip over blank and text cells
=SUM(IFERROR(--LEFT(B5:G5&0), 0))
```

Comment: Because it will throw an error when one of the cells is blank.

Comment: Try the amended formula above.

Comment: I love your idea and upvoted it! Should the user enter a text value by mistake having the formula return a #VALUE! error may, in fact, be beneficial.

Comment: If they entered 'a text value by mistake' then perhaps they should receive a #VALUE error and not a false numerical value. However, some sort of array formula could easily provide error control.

Comment: @Variatus, wouldn't a function possibly with the range passed in as an argument be more useful than a sub procedure? (btw, I'm not allowed to upvote)

Comment: ++ Always prefer formulas over VBA :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - only when the formula solution is simple. Overly complicated formulas solutions can have the calculation overhead reduced significantly by vba. I was looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246535/excel-formula-sum-time-lapses-based-on-criteria earlier and saw it as a vba solution, not a formula although a complicated formula could do it.

Comment: True that. But it also depends for whom am I creating it. Many of my clients do not have macros enabled in their Office PCs. They do not worry about overheads then... They are happy to go ahead with formulas... LOL

Comment: Yeah well, some clients you have to over complicate a formula for just because they will try and edit an array formula and cannot comprehend the CSE part.

Comment: It seems a matter of taste. For most instances I prefer a worksheet to be either VBA-driven or using worksheet functions. Hybrids are more difficult to maintain because they require two sets of skills. Talking of maintenance VBA is preferable because it enables programming annotations as well as being faster to write and easier to read than complex formulas.

Answer (score 3):

## Sum of First Digits

### The Function

```
Function SFD(Range As Range) As Long
    Dim vnt As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
    vnt = Range
    For i = 1 To UBound(vnt)
        For j = 1 To UBound(vnt, 2)
            If IsNumeric(vnt(i, j)) Then
                If CLng(vnt(i, j)) > 0 Then SFD = SFD + CLng(Left(vnt(i, j), 1))
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

In cell C9 use the formula: `=SFD(B5:G5)`.

### Array Version

```
Sub SumOfFirstDigit()

    Const cRow As Long = 5
    Const cCol1 As Variant = 2
    Const cCol2 As Variant = 7
    Const cTarget As String = "C9"

    Dim j As Long
    Dim sumFirst As Long
    Dim vnt As Variant

    vnt = Range(Cells(cRow, cCol1), Cells(cRow, cCol2))

    For j = 1 To UBound(vnt, 2)
        If IsNumeric(vnt(1, j)) Then
            If CLng(vnt(1, j)) > 0 Then _
                    sumFirst = sumFirst + CLng(Left(vnt(1, j), 1))
        End If
    Next

    Range(cTarget).Value = sumFirst

End Sub
```

### Range Version

```
Sub SumOfFirstDigit2()

    Const cRow As Long = 5
    Const cCol1 As Variant = 2
    Const cCol2 As Variant = 7
    Const cTarget As String = "C9"

    Dim j As Long
    Dim sumFirst As Long

    For j = cCol1 To cCol2
        If IsNumeric(Cells(cRow, j)) Then
            If Cells(cRow, j) > 0 Then _
                    sumFirst = sumFirst + CLng(Left(Cells(cRow, j), 1))
        End If
    Next

    Range(cTarget).Value = sumFirst

End Sub
```

### Quick Repair

- You forgot `Dim cellref As Range`.
- You forgot `Set` in `Set cellref = Cells(5, colnum)`.
- You misspelled `celref` in `sumfirst = sumfirst + (Left(cellref, 1))`.
- You forgot `Set cellref = Nothing`
- `Integer` is [dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520), `Long` prevails.

### The Code

```
Sub sum_first_digit()

    Dim cellref As Range
    Dim colnum As Long
    Dim sumfirst As Long

    sumfirst = 0

    For colnum = 2 To 7
        Set cellref = Cells(5, colnum)
        sumfirst = sumfirst + (Left(cellref, 1))
    Next colnum

    Range("C9").Value = sumfirst

    Set cellref = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use formulas as @user10931127 suggested but if you still want VBA code then try this one line VBA code

```
Sub Sample()
    [C9] = [INDEX(SUM(VALUE(LEFT(A1:A6,1))),)]
End Sub
```

If you want an explanation how this works then see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells/19986324#19986324)

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub sum_first_digit()

Dim Col As Long, X As Long

For Col = 2 To 7
    X = X + Left(Cells(5, Col), 1)
Next Col

Range("C9") = X

End Sub
```

Comment: What if the one of the cells is blank or has text in it?

Comment: Will research further to understand how this worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @Variatus neither of those seemed to be the problem so I’m not sure why I would address every what if scenario

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
Sub sum_first_digit()

    Dim colnum As Integer
    Dim sumfirst As Integer
    Dim CelRef As Variant

    For colnum = 2 To 7
        CelRef = Left(Cells(5, colnum).Value, 1)
        sumfirst = sumfirst + Val(CelRef)
    Next colnum

    Range("C9").Value = sumfirst
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the variable **CellRef**. First you wrote with **2 letters L** and after with just **1 letter L**.

Always use the comand **Option Explicit** at the top of your module. It forces you declare all variables and avoid this kind of error.

Correct code:

```
Sub sum_first_digit()

    Dim colnum As Integer
    Dim sumfirst As Integer
    Dim cellref As Variant 'Change this type to another more specific (int, long or string)

    sumfirst = 0

    For colnum = 2 To 7 Step 1
        cellref = Cells(5, colnum)
        If IsNumeric(Left(cellref , 1)) Then sumfirst = sumfirst + Left(cellref , 1)
    Next colnum

    Range("C9").Value = sumfirst

End Sub
```

The error is because the variable ** celref ** is not declared and therefore is empty. Left ("", 1) is also empty. This way you're trying to add a text to a number and that's why the types are incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

Try

sumfirst + (Left(celref, 1))  is **String**

sumfirst is **Integer**

integer = string   --> error  **Type Mismatch**

```
Sub sum_first_digit()

    Dim colnum As Integer
    Dim sumfirst As Integer

    sumfirst = 0

    For colnum = 2 To 7 Step 1
        cellref = Int(Cells(5, colnum) / 10)
        sumfirst = sumfirst + cellref
    Next colnum

    Range("C9").Value = sumfirst


End Sub
```