# How can i force capitalization of first letter of each word in Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a simple Excel sheet, where users enter their first name, sometimes they don't use capital letters, so I'm trying to make the name cells capitalize first letter automatically when they fill in their name.

I tried PROPER formula but this is useful between 2 cells / columns.

When a user Enter "jose gonzalez" in the name cell and hit enter, the content become "Jose Gonzalez".

Comment: Is VBA an option?

Comment: @BigBen `When a user Enter "jose gonzalez" in the name cell and hit enter, the content become "Jose Gonzalez".` would require vba.  A formula would need to be done in another cell from the one where the data was entered.

Comment: Yep @ScottCraner I agree I just was confirming whether OP can actually use VBA (like if it's not blocked by corporate policy).

Comment: Hi, yes i can use VBA formula. Thanks for the help. I need to apply the rule on a range of cells. D2:D1000

Comment: You can combine [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells/19986324#19986324) to get what you want ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the VBA editor (Alt + F11) in the Sheet module that you're working on, paste the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Count > 1 Then
'more than one cell
Else
    If Target.Column = 5 Then
        If Len(Target) > 0 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Target)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Mine is using column E which is 5 so you would need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: You need to check if `Target` is only one cell. Otherwise this will fail.

Comment: "When a user Enter "jose gonzalez" in the name cell"

Comment: Try changing multiple cells simultaneously in column E and see what happens. `Len(Target)` will fail. (as will `Target = Application...`).

Comment: see updated answer. Also if you want it just for one cell, then you can change `target.column = 5` to `target.address = "E5"`

Comment: You could loop through target in the (unlikely) event that it's multiple cells.

Comment: Upvoted. I prefer [`Range.CountLarge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.countlarge) to `Range.Count`, but yep you've fixed the issue.

Comment: Im trying to apply the rule on a range of cells, D2:D1000

Comment: @LudwigArcache change `If Target.Column = 5 Then` to `If Not Intersect(Range("D2:D1000"), Target) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: @ScottCraner thank :)

Answer (score 0):

The formula you're looking for is:

```
=PROPER(yourcell)
```

So, if you have written josE GonzalEz in A1, typing `=PROPER(A1)` will return a nice "Jose Gonzalez" in your cell :)

Comment: The OP stated `I tried PROPER formula but this is useful between 2 cells / columns.`  The OP wants it to be done in the same cell as the data is entered.

Comment: Yes, PROPER is useful if you want to transform data between 2 cells