# Concatenate string (VBA) for particular columns

Tags: excel, vba, string, concatenation

Goal: Add the string "Z" to a select few columns for all rows except the header. Concatenate only on select headers i.e. headers defined in the array.

```
Dim header As Range
ArrayCheck = Array("CarTime", "BusTime", "PlaneTime")
LastRow = desWS1.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lcol = desWS1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For Each header In desWS1.Range(desWS1.Cells(1, 1), desWS1.Cells(1, lcol))
    For i = LBound(ArrayCheck) To UBound(ArrayCheck)
        If header = ArrayCheck(i) Then
        desWS1.Range(desWS1.Cells(2, header.Column), desWS1.Cells(LastRow, header.Column)) & "Z"
        End If
    Next i
    Next
```

all entries in these columns are of the form: yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss

Comment: So let me understand this... If the word "CarTime" is present in say Col K then you want K2:K-lastrow = Current value & "Z"?

Comment: yep exactly. so the desired output would be yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ for rows K2:K-lastrow

Comment: If you say *"all entries in these columns are of the form: yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss"* are these values real date/times or **strings** looking like date/times?

Comment: Should be real dates/times not strings

Comment: "should be" is no proof. Please check for sure! This will change the answer completely. Check the number format of a cell that contains such a value. Eg for cell A1 use the following code to test (output will be in the immediate window) `Debug.Print Range("A1").NumberFormat` and tell us what the result is.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ the format is 'General'

Comment: @JakCarty Well, then this is just text/strings and no real date/times. Excel cannot use this to calculate and does not consider it a date. For Excel this is just a text like any other text.

Comment: Sorry @Pᴇʜ, I'm still learning VBA - your point is noted, and I understand the format point now/how to check. Appreciate this

Comment: If those are actual dates then the output will be like "44081.5477564815Z". If it is a string then it will be like "2020-09-07T13:08:46Z".

Comment: The question is what are you going to do with these values? It may be worth to convert them into real date/times and then number format them as desired.

Comment: @SiddharthRout the current cell is: 2020-09-07T13:08:46, and the output i want is: 2020-09-07T13:08:46Z. So yep, you're right, it's a string.

Comment: In that case posting an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @SiddharthRout the current cell is: 2020-09-07T13:08:46, and the output i want is: 2020-09-07T13:08:46Z. So yep, you're right, it's a string. – Jak Carty 2 mins ago

In my below code, I will take a sample of both date and date stored as text. I have commented the code so you should not have a problem understanding it. But if you do then simply post back.

Is this what you are trying?

**Code:**

**WAY 1**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim ArrayCheck As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    
    ArrayCheck = Array("CarTime", "BusTime", "PlaneTime")
    
    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find last row
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
               After:=.Range("A1"), _
               Lookat:=xlPart, _
               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
               MatchCase:=False).Row
        
        '~~> Find last col
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        '~~> Loop though the cell in 1st row
        For i = 1 To lCol
            '~~> Loop through the array
            For j = LBound(ArrayCheck) To UBound(ArrayCheck)
                '~~> Check if they match
                If .Cells(1, i).Value2 = ArrayCheck(j) Then
                    '~~> Set your range from cell 2 onwards
                    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(lRow, i))
                    
                    '~~> Add "Z" to the entire range in ONE GO i.e without looping
                    '~~> To understand this visit the url below
                    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells
                    rng.Value = Evaluate("index(Concatenate(" & rng.Address & ",""Z""" & "),)")
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note**: For the sake of clarity, I am not joining the string `",""Z""" & "),)")`

**In Action**

[image]

**WAY 2**

Introducing a 2nd way

This code writes to array and then works with it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim ArrayCheck As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tmpAr As Variant
    
    ArrayCheck = Array("CarTime", "BusTime", "PlaneTime")
    
    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find last row
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
               After:=.Range("A1"), _
               Lookat:=xlPart, _
               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
               MatchCase:=False).Row
        
        '~~> Find last col
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        '~~> Loop though the cell in 1st row
        For i = 1 To lCol
            '~~> Loop through the array
            For j = LBound(ArrayCheck) To UBound(ArrayCheck)
                '~~> Check if they match
                If .Cells(1, i).Value2 = ArrayCheck(j) Then
                    '~> Set your range
                    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(lRow, i))
                    
                    '~~> Store the value in array
                    tmpAr = rng.Value2
                    
                    '~~> Work with array
                    For k = 1 To UBound(tmpAr)
                        tmpAr(k, 1) = tmpAr(k, 1) & "Z"
                    Next k
                    
                    '~~> write the array back to worksheet
                    rng.Resize(UBound(tmpAr), 1).Value = tmpAr
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: For some reason it just replaces all the entries with "Z"

Comment: I have added a 2nd way to do it. Refresh the page to see it. Try that. Does that work?