# Concat from first to the last but one in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to concat all objects but last one from column A to Column B
So far I come up with this idea

```
Set NameRange = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    For Each cell In NameRange 
    cell.Offset(, 1) = cell.Text & "," 
    Next cell
```

and I want last cell to be in the next column which is why there is Offset(,1) but without this ","

So it looks kind of like

```
A  A,
B  B,
C  C,
D  D
```

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`For Each` doesn't remember the last cell visited (unlike a `For..Next` loop), but you can work around this:

```
Set NameRange = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
For Each cell In NameRange
    cell.Offset(, 1) = cell.Text & ","
    Set last = cell
Next cell
last.Offset(, 1) = Left(last.Text, Len(last.Text))
```

and then remove the `last` comma outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid the use of `xlDown`. You may want to see [Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)
2. Avoid the use of `.Text`. You may want to see [What is the difference between .text, .value, and .value2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2?rq=1)
3. What if last row is 1? Handle that as well.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Check if last row is 1
        If lRow = 1 Then
            .Range("B1").Value = .Range("A1").Value
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        For i = 1 To (lRow - 1)
            .Range("B" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value & ","
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is another way which doesn't use a loop

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sAddr As String
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Check if last row is 1
        If lRow = 1 Then
            Range("B1").Value = .Range("A1").Value
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        sAddr = "A1:A" & (lRow - 1)
        
        .Range("B1:B" & (lRow - 1)).Value = _
        Evaluate("index(concatenate(" & sAddr & "," & """,""" & "),)")

        .Range("B" & lRow).Value = .Range("A" & lRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

[Explanation about index(concatenate())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells/19986324#19986324)