# How do I auto add word to end of text in multiple columns using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am needing to add a .mp3 to the end of each entry in two columns. I have the code below which works but I have to select each item in the column and it applies it to those cells.

But I would like to have a code that would automatically add the .mp3 to the end of any entry in column B and D.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub AppendToExistingOnRight()
Dim c as range
For each c in Selection
  If c.value <> "" Then c.value = c.value & ".mp3”
Next
End Sub
```

Any assistance would be appreciate to help make this just a little more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

A solution **without** looping. I am showing it for column`B`. Feel free to adapt it for column `D`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sAddr As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    '~~> Change sheet name as applicable
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in Col B
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Construct your range
        Set rng = Range("B1:B" & lRow)
        
        sAddr = rng.Address
        
        '~~> Append ".mp3" to the entire range in 1 go
        rng = Evaluate("index(concatenate(" & sAddr & ","".mp3""),)")
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

If you would like to understand how this works then you may want to see [Convert an entire range to uppercase without looping through all the cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells)

Answer (score 0):

I've added references to the workbook, worksheet, and set ranges which are then looped. I've also added a check to verify if ".mp3" already exists at the end of the cell. Finally, I prevented the screen from updating until the script has completed.

If you want it to run faster, specify the range (ie. `ws.Range("B1:B1000")` will check 1000 cells rather than 1048576).

```
Sub AppendToExistingOnRight()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Dim c As Range
Dim colB As Range: Set colB = ws.Range("B:B")
Dim colD As Range: Set colD = ws.Range("D:D")

For Each c In colB
  If c.Value <> "" And Right(c.Value, 4) <> ".mp3" Then c.Value = c.Value & ".mp3"
Next

For Each c In colD
  If c.Value <> "" Then c.Value = c.Value & ".mp3"
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below sub. If your data is same in `Column B` and `Column D` then you can use one loop.

```
Sub AddMP3()
Dim bRng As Range, dRng As Range, mRng As Range

Set bRng = Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
Set dRng = Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each mRng In bRng
        mRng = mRng & ".mp3"
    Next

    For Each mRng In dRng
        mRng = mRng & ".mp3"
    Next

Set bRng = Nothing
Set dRng = Nothing
End Sub
```