# Excel VBA - Date Substitute

Tags: excel, vba

I am about to substitute data format in entire row by using VBA in MS Excel from text format from YY-MM-DD into DD-MM-YY. I tried to remove apostrophe from the beginning but then date 21-04-02 is recognized as 21.04.2002 instead of 02.04.2021, so need to substitute characters within each ell in entire row.

In below code I need to add replacing part for each cell

```
Sub DateSub()
   Dim strInput As String, strOutput As String
   Dim LastRowcheck As Long, n1 As Long, rowschecktodelete As Long

  LastRowcheck = Sheets("T1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For n1 = 2 To LastRowcheck
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(n1, 2)
     'HERE SHOULD BE REPLACING PART
        Sheets("T1").Cells(n1, 2).Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "yy-mm-dd"
   End With
  Next n1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Comment: A formula can solve this. Let's say your date in `A1` = `'21-04-02`. Put the formula `=DATE(2000+LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,4,2),RIGHT(A1,2))` in cell `B1`. If you still want vba then use the same logic there

Comment: I am sure that will work, but I am the VBA newbie and I miss something to make it work properly, I would like to replace this way each cell in the column B.                                                                                                                    Sheets("T1").Cells(n1, 2) = DATE(2000+LEFT(nl,2),MID(A1,4,2),RIGHT(nl,2))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want VBA then you can convert the entire range in one go without looping as shown below

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sAddr As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Set rng = Range("T1:T" & lRow)
        sAddr = rng.Address

        rng = Evaluate("index(DATE(2000+LEFT(" & sAddr & _
                              ",2),MID(" & sAddr & _
                              ",4,2),RIGHT(" & sAddr & _
                              ",2)),)")
                              
        rng.NumberFormat = "DD-MM-YY"
    End With
End Sub
```

To understand how this works, please see [Convert an entire range to uppercase without looping through all the cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells)

**In Action**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Text to Columns` method.

For example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub convDates()
    Const convCol As Long = 1
    Dim WS As Worksheet, Rng As Range
    
'change sheetName, convCol and destination to your specifications if this works for you.
    
Set WS = Worksheets("sheet5")
With WS
    Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, convCol), .Cells(.Rows.Count, convCol).End(xlUp))
    Rng.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=.Cells(1, convCol + 1), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        textqualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _
        Consecutivedelimiter:=True, _
        Tab:=False, _
        semicolon:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        other:=False, _
        fieldinfo:=Array(1, xlYMDFormat)
End With
End Sub
```

In the code above `convCol` is the column you wish to convert (col A in this example)
and also note that we are writing the results one column to the left (see the `Destination:=` argument.

If you are satisfied with how this is working, you can change `convCol` to your column of interest (probably column B or 2) and, by removing the `+1` from the `Destination:=` parameter, overwrite the original data.

[image]