# How to add single quote in front of all the rows in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that contains first column with date, I want the text to stay as "May-21" but in the form of string. The cell value should be May-21 but when I try to convert it into string it using 5 digit number. If I keep the column in date format it'll automatically pick May first so even if the format is MMM-yy the value will be 5/1/2021, I want to treat the column as string not date any suggestions?

Here's what I have tried in VBA:

```
Columns("A:A").Select        
Selection.NumberFormat = "'[$-en-US]mmm-yy;@"
```

Comment: It may be useful to create a table of the month Names and numbers and `vlookup` from the month #. `Concat` month with the last 2 numbers of the `year` and you should be about there without using VBA. `=vlookup(Month([date]),Table,2,0)&"-"&right(Year([date]),2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

This below method uses the `INDEX()` AND `TEXT()` formula to convert the entire range in one go. without looping. For more explanation you may want to see [Convert an entire range to uppercase without looping through all the cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sAddr As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in Col A in input sheet
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
        sAddr = rng.Address
        
        rng = Evaluate("INDEX(TEXT(" & sAddr & ",""'[$-en-US]mmm-yy;@""),)")
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

**Note:** If you do not want to use VBA then use the formula `=TEXT(A1,"'[$-en-US]mmm-yy;@")`. Put this in Cell B1 and drag it down. Finally copy paste as values.

Comment: I am able to change the format but after the formatting, if you see it in the value field on the top it'll still show the date with day, month & year

Comment: No. it doesn't for me. It shows `'May-21` for me

Comment: Updated my post above with screenshot to show formula bar. You may have to refresh the page to see it.