# Running same VBA code for a range of columns (one column at a time)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, text-to-column

I have a range of dates which I need to convert to **'MM/DD/YYYY** format (but as text) every month.

[image: Range]

I used to manually convert these by using this formula `=TEXT(Cell Ref.,"MM/DD/YYYY")`. See picture above. I have recently started using below VBA code to save my time (there are around 18 columns with 200K rows worth of data every month).

```
Sub MM_DD_YYYY()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rng As Range

Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

For Each rng In Selection
rng.Value = "+text(" & rng.Value & ",""MM/DD/YYYY"")"
Next rng

    Selection.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This code works fine if I select one column but fails if I select multiple columns because it has text to column element (which obviously only works for one column at a time). Is it possible to run the code one column at a time after selecting entire range without breaking it?

By the way, I have tried below alternatives of text to column:

1. Simulating F2+Enter. This works but takes a lot of time.

```
For Each rng In Selection
    SendKeys "{F2}", True
    SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
Next
```

2. Doesn't work for some reason.

```
Selection.Value = Selection.FormulaR1C1
```

3. Doesn't work for some reason.

```
For Each rng In Selection
Selection.Value = Selection.Value
Next rng
```

I would really appreciate your help or suggestion here. Thanks.

Comment: Why you cannot just copy all data into another column and change the date format will do??? Custom format`mm/dd/yyyy` lol?

Comment: `Selection.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"`

Comment: It is possible, but why to iterate and use TextToColumns?

Comment: Quick question.... `I have a range of dates` Are these actual dates or dates stored as Text?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I can't just format cells because I have to load data to a different system which only accepts this format. The output has a apostrophe at the beginning i.e. it's a text. That is why I was using text formula. `Selection.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"` also doesn't work. range of dates are actual dates but output should be a text.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Just curious, is it possible to make it to work for more than one range. Example, I have dates in Col A and Col C (Col B has some other data). Current code doesn't work because if I select only Col A and Col C, they are now 2 ranges. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yup. Updated my post. You may have to refresh the page to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The output has a apostrophe at the beginning i.e. it's a text. That is why I was using text formula. Selection.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY" also doesn't work. range of dates are actual dates but output should be a text. – ram singh 12 secs ago

Try this. For explanation see [Convert an entire range to uppercase without looping through all the cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells). The below code uses `INDEX()` and `TEXT()`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sAddr As String

    Set rng = Range("A1:C5") '<~~ Change this to relevant range
    sAddr = rng.Address

    rng = Evaluate("index(""'"" & Text(" & sAddr & ",""MM/DD/YYYY""),)")
End Sub
```

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]

**EDIT**

> @SiddharthRout Just curious, is it possible to make it to work for more than one range. Example, I have dates in Col A and Col C (Col B has some other data). Current code doesn't work because if I select only Col A and Col C, they are now 2 ranges. Any thoughts? – ram singh 15 mins ago

Is this what you want?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ar As Range
    Dim sAddr As String

    Set rng = Range("A1:A5,C1:C5") '<~~ Sample range
    
    For Each ar In rng.Areas
        sAddr = ar.Address

        ar = Evaluate("index(""'"" & Text(" & sAddr & ",""MM/DD/YYYY""),)")
    Next ar
End Sub
```

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]

Comment: @ram singh: I would like to remind you that we here, when somebody answer our question, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that the code works...