# How to make each cell's length to be 5?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with 7000+ names. I want to make each name's length not excess to `5`. Here is what I have tried which doesn't work

```
Sub del()
    Dim myCell
    Set myCell = ActiveCell
    Dim count As Integer

    count = Len(ActiveCell)

    While count > 5
        myCell = Left(myCell, Len(myCell) - 1)
        myCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Set myCell = ActiveCell
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

No need for VBA. You can use a formula, `=Left(A1,5)`, to get the first `5` characters of the cell. Simply autofill the formula down.

[image]

If you still want VBA then also you do not need to loop. See this example. For explanation see [Convert an entire range to uppercase without looping through all the cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
        rng = Evaluate("index(left(" & rng.Address(External:=True) & ",5),)")
    End With
End Sub
```

In the above code I am assuming that the data is in column `A` in `Sheet1`. Change as applicable.

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: I wonder how `Evaluate` performs compared to a loop over an array. Any experiences?

Comment: I did a quick test. My Test Results on `A1:A1048576`

**1.** `Evaluate` and `Array` both took 4 seconds. So I would prefer `Evaluate` in this scenario because of lesser lines of code. **2.** Looping through the range took 1 minute and 50 seconds.

Comment: Amazing job. Well looping the range was clear to be the longest ^^ But good to know that `Evaluate` performs so good, because I like how easy it is to do that task with `Evaluate`.

Comment: Helpful to discover this interesting time behaviour, possibly version dependant? - Friendly hint: using VBA I'd urgently recommend to *fully qualify* even the range address string via  `External:=True` argument as follows: `rng = Evaluate("index(left(" & rng.Address(External:=True) & ",5),)")` @SiddharthRout

Comment: @T.M. Yes it s a good suggestion. I have updated the above post :)