# Change a column's contents to uppercase in all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through each worksheet in my workbook and change the text in column G to upper case, with the header column remaining unchanged.

```vb
Sub capitalize_columns()
    
    Dim wb as ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws as Worksheet 
    set wb = ThisWorkbook 
    
    For Each ws in wb.worksheets
         With ws
         Dim last_row as Long 
         last row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
         Dim capital_range As Range
         Set capital_range = ws.Range("G2:G" & last_row)    
         capital_range.Value = capital_range.Parent.Evaluate("Index(UPPER(" & name_range.Address & "),)")
         End With
     Next ws
End Sub
```

The script runs but I it doesn't produce my desired result of capitalizing the everything in column G with the exception of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating the upper case part. All you need is `UCase()` in a loop like shown here:

```
Sub capitalize_columns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim row As Long
    Dim last_row As Long
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
       With ws
         last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' use column A to find last row
         For row = 2 To last_row ' start at row 2
           .Range("G" & row) = UCase(.Range("G" & row))
         Next
       End With
     Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks much! This works. Writing long, over-complicated code is part of learning, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good! `Index(UPPER())` is a faster way as it doesn't loop as mentioned in [Convert an entire range to uppercase without looping through all the cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells). Your code just needs few fixes.

**Fixes:**

1. Declare the objects on the top and not in the loop.
2. Find the last row of column `G` and not `A`. You may not get the true range if the column data is uneven.
3. Use `Option Explicit`. It will catch typos like `last_row` Vs `last row` and also `name_range`

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub capitalize_columns()
    Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim capital_range As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        With ws
            '~~> Find last row in col G
            last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
            
            Set capital_range = .Range("G2:G" & last_row)
            
            capital_range.Value = .Evaluate("Index(UPPER(" & capital_range.Address & "),)")
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```