# Format string to date with double digit day and month using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date

My worksheet has these formulas. Some of the values in column T are Date and some are string or general:

[image]

And its values:

[image]

I have this [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) code that loops through each cell in a column and convert the string value to a date and format the date. However, it is working perfectly fine with a double-digit month and day, but not single digits. What is the cause of problem and how can I make it to always result in double digit, i.e "01 - 02 -2021", *not* "1/2/2021"?

```
Sub Date_format()

    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    i = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' First I applied mm - dd as the same as the work sheet
    ActiveSheet.Range("T2:T" & i).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"

    For Each Cel In ActiveSheet.Range("T2:T" & i)
        If Not Cel.Value = "n/a" Then

            ' Then I applied dd - mm to swap the day and month
            Cel.Value = Format(DateValue(Cel.Value), "dd - mm - yyyy")
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Once I applied `.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"` to the range, my other formula `=DAYS(TODAY(),T2)` that calculate days, are not working any more on most cells as shown in this picture:

[image]

Comment: Add `.Range("T2:T" & i).NumberFormat = "dd - mm - yyyy"` before the FOR loop

Comment: `once I applied .NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy" to the range my other formula =DAYS(TODAY(),T2) that calculate days are not working anymore on some cells` Which cells?

Comment: You mention you have applied `.NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"`  but T5 shows "dd-mm-yyyy"? Can you also update the question with the current code that you are using?

Comment: @SiddharthRout first I applied `mm - dd` as same as work sheet. then I re-applied `dd - mm`   to swap the day and month. I think the problem is with the date format?

Comment: Change `Cel.Value = Format(DateValue(Cel.Value), "dd - mm - yyyy")` to `Cel.Value =DateValue(Cel.Value)`. You have already applied the format. no need to apply it in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, add

```
.Range("T2:T" & i).NumberFormat = "dd - mm - yyyy"
```

before the `FOR` loop.

Here is another way to achieve what you want **without** using loops.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Date_format()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        '~~> Last row in Col T
        lRow = .Range("T" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        With .Range("T2:T" & lRow)
            .NumberFormat = "dd - mm - yyyy"
            
            .Value = ws.Evaluate("index(IF(" & .Address & _
                     "<>""n/a"",DATEVALUE(" & .Address & "),""n/a""),)")
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

This approach uses `EVALUATE` with `INDEX`, `IF` and `DATEVALUE` to do the conversion without using any loops. For explanation on how it works, please see [Convert an entire range to uppercase without looping through all the cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells)

Comment: please see the question I have tried to explain it with pictures

Answer (score 2):

Please, try transforming this part:

```
If Not Cel.Value = "n/a" Then
    Cel.Value = Format(DateValue(Cel.Value), "dd - mm - yyyy")
End If
```

as:

```
If Not Cel.Value = "n/a" Then
    Cel.NumberFormat = "dd - mm - yyyy"
    Cel.Value = Format(DateValue(Cel.Value), "dd - mm - yyyy")
End If
```

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Even, better... :)

Comment: can you explain it please! why it does not work in single line?

Comment: @Ibn e Ashiq Didn't it work in a single line? What do you mean by "does not work in single line"? It should work... I only tried adapting your existing code inside the loop. But placing such a line before the loop (to format all the range), it will do the job (in a simpler) code. And a little faster, not formatting of each cell...

Comment: thanks for detailed answer as I applied `.NumberFormat = "dd - mm - yyyy"` my other formula does not work which is `=DAYS(TODAY(),T2)`

Comment: @Ibn e Ashiq This means that what you have in column "T:T" **is not formatted as date**, after running your code in this way. I would firstly suggest to delete all your code, keeping only `ActiveSheet.Range("T2:T" & i).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"`. It looks that what you said is not true: The column is formatted as `Date`, not as text... It becomes text after applying of your code.  The above line formats it (being a Date) as you required and your code creates strings instead...